# how to set absolute path mapping in Jersey

Tags: servlets, jersey, jax-rs

Let's say I have an web.xml.

```
web.xml
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>org.foo.rest.MyApplication</servlet-name>
    </servlet>
    ...
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>org.foo.rest.MyApplication</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    ...
</web-app>
```

My resource class, I have defined the path as:

```
@Path("/")
public class Resource {
    @Path("/resources/{anything}")
    @GET
    public void doAnything(@PathParam("anything") String anything){
    }
}
```

I want to configure it, so that user can hit the url with
http://localhost:8080/myapp/resources/1234

Currently user has to issue
http://localhost:8080/myapp/resources/resources/123

if web.xml and Resource class cannot be changed, any configuration I can do to make it works?

**A bit of History**
I am tasked to remove Enunciate 1 from a Spring 3 project. The existing web.xml used "EnunciateJerseyServletContainer" as servlet. I replaced it with "com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet", but the path has changed then. So I was asking, without modifying existing code, can i change some cofnigurations to make the original endpoints works?

Comment: Just curious, why can't you change it? And what Jersey version are you using?

Comment: If you're not the webapp developer but the server admin, just use an URL rewrite rule. All decent server proxies (httpd, nginx, etc) support it. If you're however the webapp developer itself, then I don't at all understand "cannot be changed".

Comment: updated my question. I am working on a legacy code base.

Comment: _"The existing web.xml used "EnunciateJerseyServletContainer" as servlet. I replaced it with "com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet""_ - So why can't you change the url-pattern in the web.xml also?

Comment: because someone has use ESAPI to validate the input url pattern, changing it will trigger the security warning. I am not familiar with how the security setting work yet.

Comment: I also ran into this issue migrationing from Jersey 1.x to 2.x. Looks like they changed it as a part of the jersey migration.